# Putting Ajax Partial View Templates in Assets/javascripts Directory Instead of Views Directory, Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am using ajax requests to render partials.  It works, but something just doesn't feel right about the design that I am using.

**Setup**: As an example, I made a basic blogger application that just makes each of the restful actions (index, show, edit, create, destroy) respond to ajax requests.

Here is the current flow of events:

1. A link is clicked with the `remote: true` option
2. The corresponding controller's action responds to javascript
3. Goes to ***`views/bloggers/correspondingActionName.js.coffee`***
4. Inside of that ***views/bloggers*** directory are all the `js.coffee` files which correspond to the restful actions.  Each of these `js.coffee` files usually render an `html.erb` partial. Example:

***views/bloggers/edit.js.coffee***

```
$form = $('<%= j render("edit") %>').hide()
$bloggers = $('#listing_bloggers')
$bloggers.after($form)
$form.fadeIn 100
```

***views/bloggers/_edit.html.erb***

```
<div id="edit_blogger">
    <h1>Editing blogger</h1>
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', bloggers_path, remote: true%>
</div>
```

The part that doesn't feel right about all of this is that it feels as if those ***js.coffee.erb*** files should not be within the views directory but instead be located inside the ***assets/javascripts*** directory.

I attempted to put those ***js.coffee.erb*** files up in the ***assets/javascripts*** directory, but it kept throwing an error regarding the `j render` method.

**Question**: Is there a way to make it work the way I would like it to?  That is: keep all the javascript (even the javascript related to ajax requests) up inside the assets/javascripts directory? Or, is there a more conventional strategy than either of the ways I have described above?  Or: why is the way I am doing it now the best way, because it feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you're doing it right now is, in fact, the conventional Rails way. Because the files are *.erb, which stands for "Embedded Ruby", this means they are being rendered **server** side (and must be rendered server side). The assets directory is for all **client** side files. I think it makes the most sense if you break down everything that is happening, remembering that the most important thing to understand about Rails is defaults:

1. User clicks on link, which makes an AJAX request to your server, at Controller#action.
2. Controller does whatever you tell it to do in the `action` method
3. Controller renders the corresponding view in `views/controller/action.js.erb` by defauly, because the request received was an AJAX request. If the request had been an HTML request, then the default view is `views/controller/action.html.erb`.
4. Javascript returned by server is executed on the client side, in a browser.